# jQuery find input in next table cell

Tags: jquery

I have a simple table with select and options in one row and input fields in the other.

```
... | tr1      | tr2
----+----------+--------------
... | select1  | input1
... | select2  | input2
```

within the td I'm running a small jquery statement to select to set the option to a value I get from twig. It's working without an issue.

Depending on the value of the select I'd like to add a css class to the next input in the same row.

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <select id="{{ma.persnr}}{{ma.user}}">
        <option value="">-</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
   </td>
   <td>
     <input type="text" class="amountsum" tabindex="-1" value="0,00" maxlength="6" placeholder="_,__" name="timesetamountmon[]">
     <script>
          $('#{{ma.persnr}}{{ma.user}} option[value="{{varabsence}}"]').attr('selected', 'selected');

          if('{{varabsence}}' != ''){
               console.log('{{varabsence}}');
               $('#{{ma.persnr}}{{ma.user}}').parent().next().find('.amountsum').addClass('bg-red');
          }

      </script>
   </td>
</tr>
```

thankful for any suggestion on how to find the element I'm looking for.

Comment: Why use jquery to do that - surely you can use whatever syntax that is to add a selected attribute and class.  Also what's not working about the above code?

Comment: hi @Pete, selecting the value works, now I'd like to add a class to the next input in the next tablecell, which is not working.

Comment: Does `console.log('{{varabsence}}');` show something on debug console?

Comment: yes. it shoes the correct value.

Comment: And the input does not have the `bg-red` class?

Comment: no, that's the issue, I don't find the input with jquery. I thought that was the right aproach.

Comment: if I do `$('#{{ma.persnr}}{{ma.user}}').addClass('bg-red');` the correct select get's the class, but I'm unable to get upwards, inwards and select the input based on it's class aparently

Comment: I tested and it is working fine. Is your HTML valid? You show us only the `<tr>` part, so we can't guess, but `<tr>` tags need to be wrapped by at least a `<table>` one. (then `<tbody>` will be added automatically if not already in the DOM)

Comment: Please can you edit your question and create [mcve] in a snippet with your rendered html and jquery.  But again, why are you using jquery for this and not your other language?

Comment: @iArcadia, this is the code https://i.imgur.com/VvVdFpO.jpg the tr's are within a table

Comment: @Pete I'm using jQuery because that's the guideline for this project. I can not post the question with complete and minimal code, because this segment is all it matters for this issue

Comment: That's the "Guideline" but you are also using the other language too and it would be better to use the other language to add the class and selected attribute, rather than using jquery. You are asking for help with a problem but not replicating the problem for us or giving us the information we ask for - if you do not want to post the rendered code, then you will not receive any help and the question is off topic for SO